# How Excel Sum a Random Given Range Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In my Excel Colum I have Latitude and Longitude. I want to plus or minus some random range [ 0.000001 to 0.0000005] this range could be + or - with selected Latitude and Longitude. How can I do it.

Ex- 79.913951 => 79.913953 or 79.913949
6.793891 => 6.793893 or 6.793889

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RANDBETWEEN` function:

```
=(-1)^RANDBETWEEN(0;1)*RANDBETWEEN(1;5)/100000
```

[image]